# Why do we need to dereference a mutable reference in a match to change it?

Tags: rust

I'm reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/) and one thing is not clear:

```
let mut mut_value = 6;
match mut_value {
    ref mut m => {
        *m += 10;
        println!("We added 10. `mut_value`: {:?}", m);
    },
}
```

Why do we need to dereference it to change it? We already have a mutable reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A reference is an address pointer. If you were to just do `m += 10`, you'd be changing the memory address (Rust doesn't let you do this without `unsafe`). What you want to do is change the *value* at `m`. So where's the value? Follow the pointer! You do this by dereferencing.

Comment: lol. So simple. I don't know why it was so hard :D much thanks!

Comment: Pointers can be hard sometimes. Having some knowledge of C helps as well!